# Extract a subgraph without changing the vertices IDs in igraph R

Tags: r, igraph, subgraph

i want to extract a subgraph without changing the vertices IDs in the resulting graph.
I work on the Miserables graph, available at link :
http://www-personal.umich.edu/~mejn/netdata/lesmis.zip
I tried with :

```
network <- read.graph("lesmis.gml", format = "gml")    
g <- subgraph.edges(network, which(E(network)$value = 1))
```

But the IDs are numbered from 1 in the resulting subgraph.
How i can keep the IDs of the old graph ?

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I think you can't, as the internal IDs for a graph have to start at 1. But you can assign an custom id like `V(network)$id <- 1:vcount(network)`, which should be kept in the subgraphs. May I ask why you'd need that?

Comment: I want to remove such edges of the main graph and add them in another graph.
That is why if i don't keep the IDs, i can't locate the edges for deleting them from the main graph.
If you have another way to do it, tell me.

Comment: I still don't get what you want to achieve in the end (example?), but setting `V(network)$name <- V(network)$label` before building the subgraph may be of help. That way, you have clear ids to continue with.

Comment: I want to save all edges whose weight is equal to 1 in an object, then add them to a new graph and remove them from the old graph.

Comment: So you want something like `network - g` or `delete.edges(network, intersection(E(g), E(network)))`?

Comment: No it isn't what i want, i tried with `delete.edges(network, which(E(network)$value == 1))` and it works